# How to design a NoSQL based database of a sensor based IOT device service?

Tags: database, mongodb, cloud, sensors

We are designing an IOT based service which collects information like current temperature, location, status and voltage of the device at regular intervals. We are planning to use a NoSQL database (MongoDB) for storage.

We might have to deploy thousands of such devices, which might scale to millions in no time. Traditional data storage might not be the best approach in this case.

How to design the database in such a manner that it is scalable horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at MongoDB's design patterns for various applications:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-a-summary

The bucket pattern is commonly used for IOT applications that collect large amounts of streaming sensor data.